# Gateway Timeout when accessing Bluemix WEB IDE/Node.js logs

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am using Web IDE and want to see the log by clicking on the arrow.I can only see an empty "Untitled" page. The Node.js app is running normally. Live edit is switch off.

After some minutes:

**Gateway Timeout**

The proxy server did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.
Reference #1.45bf1402.1511018717.3dddb8b

Answer (score 1):

I'm not for sure what Web IDE you are referring to. The only one I'm aware of is the DevOps (which works for me below):

[image: devops ide]

It seems to me like this error that you posted would indicate a temporary outage. Is it still an issue?

In any case, I would advise opening a support ticket if you encounter this issue again (more details about your account would help). I think the Bluemix proxy will time out requests if they take too long.